# width of a gtk.combobox with entry in vala

Tags: gtk, vala

i'm beginning with vala and i'm unable to set the width of a Gtk.ComboBox.
In Python i can do it like so:

```
combo = Gtk.ComboBox.new_with_entry()
entry = combo.get_child()
entry.set_width_chars(12)
```

in vala this:

```
var combo = new ComboBox.with_entry ();
var entry = combo.get_child();
entry.set_width_chars(12);
```

gives:

```
error: The name `set_width_chars' does not exist in the context of `Gtk.Widget'
```

altough this:

```
var combo = new ComboBox.with_entry ();
var entry = combo.get_child();
if (entry is Gtk.Entry)
    stdout.printf("Entry!\n")
```

prints "Entry!", so where is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I have extremely limited exposure to vala but I hope this helps )
The issue could be the return type from `get_child()`, it is `Gtk.Bin` function which returns `Gtk.Widget` and not `Gtk.Entry` for which `set_width_char()` is valid. This is because a child widget of `Gtk.Bin` can be any widget. Try static typecasting:

```
var entry = (Entry)combo.get_child();
```

or more convoluted version

```
var entry = combo.get_child();
((Entry)entry).set_width_chars(12);
```

And as for the successful type check to `Gtk.Entry`, although what you have `Gtk.Widget` the type is of `Gtk.Entry` as the child added to `combobox` is an entry.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Shouldn't this be "combo.get_child() as Gtk.Entry" for the safe GObject-style typecast?

Comment: @Ancurio: I am not quite sure what you mean. `get_child()` being called here is from `Gtk.Bin` and not `Gtk.ComboBox` and in `Gtk.Bin` you do not know what type the child is exactly. You can add any widget as a (only) child to `Gtk.Bin`. In case of `Gtk.ComboBox` which is a `Gtk.Bin` this child happens to be `Gtk.Entry`.

Comment: @another.anon.coward what I am saying is that the expression "some_gtk_widget as Gtk.Entry" in Vala results in "GTK_ENTRY(some_gtk_widget)" in C, which is safe because it checks the type at runtime and throws an assertion if it's the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Vala is not Python, there is no set_width_chars() function. In Vala there's a width_chars property. Try this instead:

```
entry.width_chars = 12;
```

Please check the docs at http://www.valadoc.org/#!wiki=gtk+-3.0/index . In particular: http://www.valadoc.org/#!api=gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Entry.width_chars .

EDIT: there's actually a Entry.set_width_chars(). Anyway in Vala there are properties that are usually used for this kind of things.

Comment: I don't know vala but they have this: http://www.valadoc.org/#!api=gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Entry.set_width_chars

Comment: This returns  `error: The name 'width_chars' does not exist in the context of 'Gtk.Widget'`

Comment: @jkd Of course it must be an Entry, not a generic Widget. That was the answer to the question afterall.